# how to move background when corner rotation?

Tags: javascript, background, rotation

How to move background image as corner in rotate another image

rotate:

```
 $('#ship').css({
            transform: 'rotate(' + corner + 'deg)'
        });
```

}

move background:

starx[i]=starx[i]+...

stary[i]=stary[i]+..

Comment: If you want to move only background-image  then instead of transform prop h should use background-position prop transform move's the while element while background-position moves only background-image ! See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Comment: my background is stars in canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform-origin For you Refreance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: image of ship have transform but background not move